# std::unique_ptr compiler error: Members of a derived class cannot access private members of a base class

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, unique-ptr

I get [Compiler Error C2248](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh%28v=vs.110%29) when i try to compile the following code:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


class data
{
public:

    static data parse()
    {
        data d;
        data::parse(d);
        return d;
    }

    list<std::unique_ptr<data>> l;

private:

    static void parse(data& node)
    {       }
};


int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Why? How can i fix this?
Note: I have no problem using `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Please post your actual error message, as well as sufficient code to reproduce it.

Comment: @KerrekSB You can test using the update, the error message is not in english, do you want to see it anyway?

Comment: Try adding an empty body default constructor, and add a copy constructor.

Comment: @Nick : What copy constructor could you have added that did anything meaningful?

Comment: @ildjarn I added `data(const data&){}` and the empty default constructor.

Comment: @Nick : But do you think `data(const data&){}` is actually correct? (It isn't.)

Comment: @ildjarn why it is not correct?

Comment: @Nick: the copy constructor needs to actually copy something... That is just an empty stub.

Comment: @Nick : Would you really expect to get a copy of a `data` with a list of valid pointers and have the copy end up with an empty list? I certainly hope not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to provide move operations for your type:

```
data(data&& other)
    : l(std::move(other.l))
{
}

data& operator=(data&& other)
{
    l = std::move(other.l);
    return *this;
}
```

And, since you'll have added a user-declared constructor, you'll also need a user-declared default constructor:

```
data() { }
```

My understanding is that your code is correct as-is, per the final C++11 language standard.  Visual C++ does not fully implement the final specification for when move operations are implicitly generated (as of the Visual C++ 2012 RC).  The specification for when implicit move operations are generated changed several times very late in the standardization process.

If you have a class type `C` that has any data member that is movable but noncopyable, Visual C++ will not generate an implicit move constructor or move assignment operator, and the implicit copy constructor and copy assignment operator are both suppressed by the presence of the move-only data member.  In other words, if you want ot aggregate move-only types, you must provide the move operations for the aggregating class yourself.

(At least, this is my understanding from experimentation with the compiler.)

Comment: I don't know what are move ctor and move assignment operator and what they are for. Can you explain me?

Comment: If you want an aggregate, you better say `data() = default;`!

Comment: @KerrekSB:  The OP is using Visual C++, which does not support defaulted and deleted special member functions.  If one is using a mythical compiler that supports the entirety of C++11 and has no bugs, then none of this is necessary and the code should be fine as-is.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I see. That's a shame.

Comment: @Nick:  See [Can someone please explain move semantics to me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me)  `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a move-only type:  you cannot copy objects of that type, you can only move them.  This is because a given `std::unique_ptr<T>` object is the unique owner of a given `T` object (hence it's name).  If you could copy it, then it would no longer be the unique owner (there would then be two owners).

Answer (score 5):

First things first, VC++ doesn't automatically generate a move ctor and move assignment operator yet, which means you need to define them yourself.

Next, when you return local variables, the compiler first tries to *move* them before actually going the usual route of copying them. However, to do that, it needs a move ctor. Since it doesn't have that, it tries the usual copy and through the generated copy ctor automatically invokes the copy constructor of `std::list` which in turn tries to invoke the copy ctor of its element type, which is private in `std::unique_ptr`s case.

You need to either define an appropriate move ctor or a copy ctor that doesn't invoke `std::unique_ptr`'s copy ctor (i.e., make a deep copy of the content).

Comment: I don't know what are move ctor and move assignment operator and what they are for. Can you explain me?

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph of your answer.  `return std::move(local_variable);` is incorrect in all cases of which I am aware:  it suppresses NRVO and the compiler should prefer move operations over copy operations when they are available (Visual C++ will correctly select the move constructor in this case).

Comment: @James: Right-y, that last paragraph somehow survived my edit. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  (C++11 specific) Items in a `list` must be copyable or movveable.  A `unique_ptr` is not copyable by-design, but it is moveable, so long as the controlled type is also moveable.

Your type, `data` is not moveable because you have not implemented move semantics and the compiler did not do it for you.

Implement move semantics, and you can use `unique_ptr` in a `list`:

```
data(ddata&&) {};
```

According to thhe Standard, a move constructor would be generated for your class by the compiler.  However, VS10 does not support this -- this might be the problem your'e running in to.

For further reference, see my post on CR: [Canonical Implementation of Move Semantics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12954/canonical-implementation-of-move-semantics)

Comment: A `unique_ptr` is *always* movable, no matter the "controlled type".